# Sklearn set_params takes exactly 1 argument?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to use SkLearn [Bayes classification](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB.html#sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB.set_params).

```
 gnb = GaussianNB()
 gnb.set_params('sigma__0.2')
 gnb.fit(np.transpose([xn, yn]), y)
```

But I get:

```
set_params() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

---

now I try to use this code:

```
gnb = GaussianNB()
arr = np.zeros((len(labs),len(y)))
arr.fill(sigma)
gnb.set_params(sigma_ = arr)
```

And get:

```
ValueError: Invalid parameter sigma_ for estimator GaussianNB
```

Is it wrong parameter name or value?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`set_params()` takes only keyword arguments, as can be seen in the documentation. It is declared as `set_params(**params)`.

So, in order to make it work, you need to call it with keyword arguments only: `gnb.set_params(some_param = 'sigma__0.2')`

Comment: Could you explain me? The parameter of interest is: `sigma_` : array, shape = [n_classes, n_features], as it written in docs. So, how should I set it?

Comment: Maybe try omitting the underscore? I can't find a list of accepted parameters.

Comment: It gives the same result.

Comment: Try outputting the current parameters, for example using `print gnb.get_params()`, and see if you can find the parameter name you need.

Comment: "The former have parameters of the form <component>__<parameter>" - this is from docs. I think that <parameter> is my sigma, but what is <component>?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65583/discussion-between-mezgrman-and-leonidas).

Comment: Did you try GaussianNB.__sigma=0.2?

Comment: And if your params are a dict, you must pass them as `gnb.set_params(**params_dict)`

Answer (score 68):

I just stumbled upon this, so here is a solution for multiple arguments from a dictionary:

```
from sklearn import svm
params_svm = {"kernel":"rbf", "C":0.1, "gamma":0.1, "class_weight":"auto"}
clf = svm.SVC()
clf.set_params(**params_svm)
```

Comment:  been waiting years to figure this out. See this answer for more details on how this works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters

Comment: This is what I was searching for

Answer (score 4):

It is written in documentation that the syntax is:

> set_params(**params)

These two stars mean that you need to give keyword arguments ([read about it here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36908/1090562)). So you need to do it in the `form your_param = 'sigma__0.2'`

Comment: Yes, this is the correct answer. The python error is misleading and should say you should provide kwargs

Answer (score 3):

`sigma_` is an instance attribute which is computed during training.  You probably aren't intended to modify it directly.

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
import numpy as np

X = np.array([[-1,-1],[-2,-1],[-3,-2],[1,1],[2,1],[3,2]])
y = np.array([1,1,1,2,2,2])

gnb = GaussianNB()
print gnb.sigma_
```

Output:

```
AttributeError: 'GaussianNB' object has no attribute 'sigma_'
```

More code:

```
gnb.fit(X,y) ## training
print gnb.sigma_
```

Output:

```
array([[ 0.66666667,  0.22222223],
       [ 0.66666667,  0.22222223]])
```

After training, it is possible to modify the `sigma_` value.  This might affect the results of prediction.

```
gnb.sigma_ = np.array([[1,1],[1,1]])
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that `GaussianNB` has only one parameter and that is `priors`.

From the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB.html)

```
 class sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB(priors=None)
```

The `sigma` parameter you are looking for is, in fact, an attribute of the class GaussianNB, and cannot be accessed by the methods `set_params()` and `get_params()`.

You can manipulate `sigma` and `theta` attributes, by feeding some `Priors` to GaussianNB or by fitting it to a specific training set.